# Spring Security intercept-url is not matching Wildcard

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security

I try to implement security for my application using spring security.
I intercept page using `intercept-url`, for example:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logList*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    <logout />
    <remember-me/>
</http>
```

at the first time i try to access the log for anonymous user using url: localhost/projectname/logList
and the page automatically redirect to login page

but when I try access log page using url `localhost/projectname/logList/` the anonymous user can access the log page

why it can happen when the pattern `/logList*` is correct ?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the 2nd time you access the URL, you don't already have an authenticated session? There's no other explanation as to why you would be redirected to the login page the first time you try hitting it, but not the second time. Can you clarify the exact steps you are taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, AntPathRequestMatcher is used. If you add another pattern

`<intercept-url pattern="/logList/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />` then it will work.

Here are tests (Note that with RegexRequestMatcher, same pattern works for both /logList/ and /logList):

```
    @Test
public void antTest1() throws Exception {

    AntPathRequestMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/loglist*");
    MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     mockRequest.setScheme("http");
     mockRequest.setPathInfo("/logList");
    Assert.assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(mockRequest), is(true));
}

@Test
public void antTest2() throws Exception {


    AntPathRequestMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/loglist/*");
    MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     mockRequest.setScheme("http");
     mockRequest.setPathInfo("/logList/");
    Assert.assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(mockRequest), is(true));
}

@Test
public void regexTest3() throws Exception {

    RegexRequestMatcher pathMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/logList.*", "GET");
    MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     mockRequest.setScheme("http");
     mockRequest.setMethod("GET");
     mockRequest.setPathInfo("/logList/");
    Assert.assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(mockRequest), is(true));
}

@Test
public void regexTest4() throws Exception {

    RegexRequestMatcher pathMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/logList.*", "GET");
    MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     mockRequest.setScheme("http");
     mockRequest.setMethod("GET");
     mockRequest.setPathInfo("/logList");
    Assert.assertThat(pathMatcher.matches(mockRequest), is(true));
}
```

To use RegexRequestMatcher, add attribute 'request-matcher' to http and set its value to 'regex':

`<http auto-config="true" request-matcher="regex">`

Comment: Just a note that "request-matcher" requires Spring Sec 3.1+. The equivalent in versions lower than this is "path-type".

Comment: I've use path-type="regex" using spring sec 3.0, but error NullPointerExecption occurred.
I still downloading spring sec 3.1+

Answer (score 0):

Does `pattern="/logList/**"` make a difference?

Comment: I've try using ** pattern, but there is no difference